# PHP: Create ZIP with multiple script-calls

Tags: php

I would like to create a zip-file using PHP. This is no problem at all, but it is a large number of files and I would like to prevent the system from out of memory-errors or reaching the `max_execution_time`.

So I thought I could do the following:

Store the files I want to zip in a database. Now I could call my script using ajax. I could call it over and over again until there is no entry in the database (all files are zipped).

So is it possible to do something like `ZIPARCHIVE::RESUME` in PHP?

Comment: Could you not pass command line arguments to something like 7zip from php?

Comment: Unfortunately not